How to quickly find the minimum element to the right for every element of a Numpy array?
Let's say I have an array:
a = [1,4,3,6,4]

I want to get an array where for every element I have the smallest value in a to the right (inclusive). That is, for a, I would want to create an array:
[1,3,3,4,4]

Is there a quick, concise way to do this?

What should be the output for a = np.array([1,4,3,6,5,6,4])?

You question is actually ambiguous. Do you want to consider the following value or all following values?
considering all following values
compute a cumulated minimum on the reversed array with minimum.accumulate:
a = np.array([1,4,3,6,4])

out = np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1])[::-1]

Output:
array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4])

With pure python and itertools.accumulate:
from itertools import accumulate

a = [1,4,3,6,4]

out = list(accumulate(a[::-1], min))[::-1]
# [1, 3, 3, 4, 4]

considering only the next value
You could shift the values and use np.minimum:
a = np.array([1,4,3,6,4])

out = np.minimum(a, np.r_[a[1:], a[-1]])

Output:
array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4])

or compare the successive values and build a mask to modify a in place:
a = np.array([1,4,3,6,4])

m = a[:-1] > a[1:]
# or
# m = np.diff(a) < 0

a[np.r_[m, False]] = a[1:][m]

Modified a:
array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4])

difference
a = np.array([1,4,3,6,5,6,4])

np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1])[::-1]
# array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])

np.minimum(a, np.r_[a[1:], a[-1]])
# array([1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4])


I hope itertools.accumulate could give you the desired output
from itertools import accumulate
list(accumulate(a[::-1], lambda x, y: [x,y][y <= x]))[::-1]

# [1, 3, 3, 4, 4]


I just added an accumulate variant to my answer, list(accumulate(a[::-1], min))[::-1] is enough though ;)

@mozway aha, just saw that in your answer, I will delete my solution

You can leave it!

@mozway Ok, thank you, but yours is really concise, cheers!

Another possible solution is to use pandas cummin:
pd.Series(a[::-1]).cummin().iloc[::-1].values

Output:
array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4])


I think you mean you want the smallest of the elements to the right of the list (inclusively). That is the way I interpret your example. If so then this is a solution:
b = [np.min(a[i:]) for i in range(len(a))]

That is pretty concise. If you want it as another np array:
b = np.array([np.min(a[i:]) for i in range(len(a))])

EDIT:
This is an easy way of doing this but it is not as quick as mozway's way of doing it. Specifically:
out = np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1])[::-1]

which he wrote in his answer. Doing these two calculations 100_000 times takes 2.2487s for my solution and 0.0972s for mozway's solution making his solution aproximately 23x quicker. I would recommend his solution.
My solution is in fact slower than making it in pure python without numpy. Here is a solution in python without numpy:
result = [min(b) for i in range(len(a))]

This takes 0.1890s. This is still approx 2x slower than the pure numpy way but approx. 12x quicker than the blend that I provided.
The solution using pandas given by PaulS is very interesting but slow at a time of 7.7083s.
To be clear the measured times are for a 6 item long list/array and there is probably even a bigger difference for longer lists as mozway writes.

That would be a highly inefficient way. You do not need to restart everything to compute a running minimum. np.minimum.accumulate(a[::-1])[::-1] does the same efficiently (2000 times faster for 10k items, 7000 times faster for 100K, for more this might not even run)
